Is air resistance truly linear in surface area?
Air resistance is generally said to be linear in the surface area of the moving object. Out of pure curiosity, I am wondering to what degree this is an approximation, i.e., when this assumption begins to fail. For example, if I move identically shaped disks of different size at let's say 50 km/h through a medium, at what size can I expect a deviation of let's say 5% from the linear rule?
I think the linear rule cannot be right for very large objects because eventually some particles would need to move at relativistic speeds to "get out of the way" or am I mistaken about this? Similarly, quantum effects may play a role at very small sizes.
But I also wonder whether the linearity already breaks down in less extreme cases because the "A" part in "CdA" starts to influence the "Cd" part or even the behavior of the medium.

Notice that of the area is variable, the force will be variabel too, and that will not violate the linearity. In any case, the linearity is an approximation that only works in some practical range fo speeds and materials

I think I stated that in a confusing manner. I meant that we compare the same shape at different sizes, not that the area varies over time. Will adjust.

You are assuming that all air particles have to get out of the way of objects that are moving through them.  This is an invalid assumption.  Every object experiences a stagnation layer of air that resides very close to the surface of the object, and that layer does not get out of the way.  My best example: that is why rotating ceiling fans still accumulate dust on the fan blades.

Your question is the same as asking if the Cd is really constant. And we know that it varies in complicated ways, depending on the flow conditions & geometric shapes being considered.

@D.Halsey I specified that the geometric shape is held fixed. Do the flow conditions depend on the size of the object (for fixed shape)?

Yes, viscous effects depend strongly on the Reynolds number, which is directly proportional to the size.
